# faster csv loading with datetime index pandas

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am often iterating of financial price data stored in csv file. Like the accessibility of using pandas datetime objects to subset and organize data when all of my analysis is done with relation to time.

My issue is that when I am reading a file into my computers memory, bothe the `parse_dates` argument supplied top `pandas.read_csv()` and the `pandas.to_datetime()` are incredibly time costly.

Does anyone know a better way of dealing with time stamps in python that can be optimized to run over many files that need to be loaded into memory?

```
%timeit pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rgalbo\\Desktop\\Equity\\Data\\sp - working data\\30min--Adj\\AAPL_24.csv",index_col=[0])

10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop
```

with parse_date = True

```
%timeit pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rgalbo\\Desktop\\Equity\\Data\\sp - working data\\30min--Adj\\AAPL_24.csv",index_col=[0],parse_dates=True)

1 loops, best of 3: 7.5 s per loop
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your bottleneck and not I/O?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just am wondering if anyone has dealt with date time conversion and has seen issues with long time to execute

Comment: I'd try to be more isolated about your testing.  First read in the data and try the conversion as a second step, timing only that second step.  You can also try parse_dates=['column_name'], as I believe parse_dates=True forces pandas to guess what a datetime is.  Other tricks include storing your datetime in a numerical format (such as milliseconds since epoch) and storing your csv files compressed and reading them using pd.read_csv(..., compression='gzip') to trade off I/O for CPU.

Comment: when I isolate converting the dates for the index into steps, it takes longer for the conversion to be done after the I/O. I may have to try the compression or another format that is more conducive to that kind of computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after testing few options for loading & parsing a csv file with, 13,811,418 rows having, 98 unique date values, we arrived at the below snippet, and found out that if we pass the `format` param with predefined date-format ('%m/%d/%Y' in our case) we could reach `2.52 s` with Pandas.0.15.3.

```
def to_date(dates, lookup=False, **args):
    if lookup:
        return dates.map({v: pd.to_datetime(v, **args) for v in dates.unique()})
    return pd.to_datetime(dates, **args)
```

- also use coerce=True (or coarse='raise' in later versions) for enabling date-format validation, other-wise the error values are retained as string-value, and will lead to an error when any other date-time operation is performed on the dataframe column