# Should I convert my pandas datetime column to categorical?

Tags: python, pandas

I just noticed in the documentation that you can convert a date to a category. I have never tried this and won't have a chance until Monday, but is anyone doing this? I don't think I have been taking advantage of the category dtype enough even though I deal with files that have a ton of repeating data.

If I have a file with a few hundred thousand records all within 1 month (so the dates are repeating), will it be faster to convert to categories and then do .dt operations? I know I use .dt.strftime() often

It also looks like the dtype is category but it still knows it is datetime64, does that mean timedeltas operations or offsets would still work?

```
In [129]: date_s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=5))

In [130]: date_cat = date_s.astype('category')

In [131]: date_cat
Out[131]: 
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-03
3   2015-01-04
4   2015-01-05
dtype: category
Categories (5, datetime64[ns]): [2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03, 2015-01-04, 2015-01-05]

In [132]: date_cat.dt.day
Out[132]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: * given code snippet is not similar to loading date-vaules from csv
* there's no attempt shown / its very unclear as to, whether the date-value loaded using csv is directly set with `.astype('category')
* no reference-link provided to the mentioned documentation or version

Comment: sorry @LanceDacey, without the link ref, guess I've looked up 0.15.2 reference that I had copied locally. But what I was trying to say is, when loading data from csv, unless 'parse_dates' is specified, the date-string-value column will be treated as Object type; using that column directly will not provide the .dt.* accessors; did you try to load it from csv file & then set it to astype('category') directly?

Comment: are you loading from a csv file and parsing date-values to get the `datetime64[ns]` column in the dataframe?
if its about conversion time while parsing date-values from csv file, pls refer to [date parsing post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326834/faster-csv-loading-with-datetime-index-pandas/36800960#36800960)

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically called out by the documentation, see [String and datetime accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#string-and-datetime-accessors).

The `.dt` and `.str` accessors work for categorical columns as long as the categories are of the appropriate type.

As far as performance implications are concerned, the docs mention

> This has some performance implication if you have a `Series` of type
> `string`, where lots of elements are repeated (i.e. the number of unique
> elements in the Series is a lot smaller than the length of the
> Series). In this case it can be faster to convert the original Series
> to one of type category and use `.str.<method>` or `.dt.<property>` on
> that.

For example,

```
date_s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=5).repeat(10000))
date_s_cat = date_s.astype('category')

%timeit date_s.dt.day
%timeit date_s_cat.dt.day

10.4 ms ± 497 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
8.84 ms ± 793 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Although your mileage may vary.